# How to display a plot in Jenkins with Groovy script?

Tags: xml, jenkins, plot, groovy, jenkins-plugins

I'm currently trying to display the plot of an `XML` file in Jenkins by using a `system Groovy script`.

```
import hudson.plugins.plot.*

def plot = new Plot(csvFileName: "random.csv",
                    series: [[file: "report_cpu_sum.callisto.xml",
                              xpath: "xmllog/*",
                              nodeType: "NODESET",
                              url: ""]],
                    exclZero: false,
                    group: 'Groovy_CPU')
```

I can successfully create the `plot object`, but after reading the API docs for the `plot plugin` I can't understand how I actually display the `plot object` I just created. At first I thought I would do something like:

```
def pub = new PlotPublisher()
pub.addPlot(plot)
pub.getRequiredMonitorService()
```

However, the ouput of this is simply: `script returned: BUILD`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the way to go for using plots with Groovy code in Jenkins is with a Pipeline project.

These projects even have access to a 'Snippet Generator' that helps with creating your code.